# Incorrect NYC Subway data from HERE

Tags: here-api

Trying to get the specific subway lines that service a subway station in NYC given a lat/long. HERE is returning some data, but it's incomplete.

I'm using the following endpoint--

https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&in=40.734376,-73.990714&return=transport

It's returning the bus stations as well, but the only one I care about is
{"place":{"name":"Union Sq - 14 St","type":"station","location":{"lat":40.734789,"lng":-73.99073},"id":"717081137"},"transports":[{"mode":"subway","name":"L","color":"#A7A9AC","textColor":"#000000","headsign":"8 Av"},{"mode":"subway","name":"L","color":"#A7A9AC","textColor":"#000000","headsign":"Canarsie - Rockaway Pkwy"},{"mode":"subway","name":"L","color":"#A7A9AC","textColor":"#000000","headsign":"Myrtle - Wyckoff Avs"}]}

The Union Square 14th st subway station has the L/N/Q/R/W/4/5/6 subway lines. Is this an error with HERE data or am I missing something in my query?

Answer (score 0):

Your co-ordinates for the Union Square 14th st subway station seems misplaced. You can get all the subway lines L/N/Q/R/W/4/5/6 by below query:

https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations?apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY&return=transport&in=40.735088,-73.989952